# Not able to track htaccess issue, How to implement IF ELSE in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with htaccess to execute a rule and if rule matches then do not check for another rule. which i am trying to figure out from last few hours. Below is the sample code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase / 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/projectname/$
   #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !projectname/(storage)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectname/abc/dist/$1 [L] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  projectname/(storage)$ 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectname/storage/$1 [L]

   Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} projectname/(.*)$ 
   #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !projectname/(storage)$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(html?|png|woff|ttf|eot|svg|woff2|jpg|gif|xml|rss|png|css|js|json)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectname/#/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectname/abc/dist/$1 [L]
```

I want to load everything from projectname/abc/dist folder but not for the case when i have storage inside url then i want to load the data from storage folder only.
So as per rules defined here everything works fine but when i have storage inside url/src for image it still checks /projectname/abc/dist/storage/xxxx.png instead of checking  /projectname/storage/xxxx.png as defined in htaccess rule.

I have tried using [S=5] skip with storage rule in htaccess does not works from reference http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html.

Also as per my understanding [L] is the last so it should stop the htaccess after storage rule but it does not.

I have tried implementing IF ELSE in htaccess but the examples i tried for IF ELSE does not help even.
reference https://blogs.apache.org/httpd/entry/new_in_httpd_2_4
reference http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html (check Skip IF ELSE stanza)

Any Idea would be useful.

Comment: try adding **<base href="/projectname/stroge/">** in head section of your webpage

Comment: That's already been added solved reload problem as well. @starkeen. No may be a miss added /projectname/. let me try.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Would a appreciate a short feedback :)

Comment: No it did not work @Hello Fishy.. it stopped Angular from loading. I have sorted out for now by placing Angular in a separate directory from laravel. But yes i will be looking for solution to my problem i mentioned. Once i get it i will leave a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to load from 'projectname/abc/dist'-folder EXCEPT when there is 'storage' anywhere in the requested URI?! If I got that right, that might help:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !storage
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectname/abc/dist/$1 [END,P]
```

I added [P] for 'proxy' assuming that you don't want to show the customer he is rewritten by your server. If you don't mind seeing them, just leave that out.

Comment: That's surprising oO Because END, in contrast to L, stops processing of rewrites at all for that request: Using the [END] flag terminates not only the current round of rewrite processing (like [L]) but also prevents any subsequent rewrite processing from occurring in per-directory (htaccess) context.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [`L|last`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) doesn't mean stop all processing.

> If you are using RewriteRule in either .htaccess files or in  sections, it is important to have some understanding of how the rules are processed. The simplified form of this is that once the rules have been processed, the rewritten request is handed back to the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it.

See also [Ruleset Processing](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset) for how this works.

---

To load from `/project/abc/dist`, except when there's `storage` in the URL, you must first check for `storage`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /storage/
RewriteRule /([^/]*$ /project/storage/$1 [L]
```

And then

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/abc/dist/$1 [L]
```

Finally, to prevent a rewrite loop, prefix the rules with

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

---

Everything together

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /storage/
RewriteRule /([^/]*$ /project/storage/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/abc/dist/$1 [L]
```